# Reset Blender inputs?

Tags: interface

I am NOT looking to factory reset my ENTIRE blender, i am just looking to reset the default key map,  i did something, an option popped up to change binds and before i could react i mis-clicked and am stuck with deleting by right click instead of selecting by right clicking, ive looked around but so far, only factory resetting? has popped up which resets my entire blender, which i'm not looking to do. i feel that i have to repeat that because all i have found is to factory reset.

i am running 2.79 sorry i didnt specify

Answer (score 0):

First, the new shortcut should not remain each time you start blender, unless you save user settings.

The only trick is finding it. Open User preferences and go to the Input tab. In 2.80+ this is now under Keymap.

Use the search field to find "delete". Alternatively, you may want to search for the key-binding, in which case you can search for "right mouse".

If you changed an existing shortcut, there will be an arrow to go back to factory settings. If it is a new shortcut you added, there will be an X to remove the shortcut.

[image: searching Input settings]

After correcting the shortcut, click Save User Settings.